# PHP - put a variable in session only if link is clicked

Tags: php

how can I put a variable in session **only** if link is clicked?

Note: My link have to submit a form at the same time.

Comment: Links are not for submitting forms.

Comment: Use submit buttons to submit forms, not links. Links are for going straight to a pre-determined URI. Submit buttons are for submitting user input to a URI.

Comment: I have forgotten to precise that I submit my form with javascrit like this : onclick="document.forms['form1'].submit();"

I can also use a button :)

Comment: The question is quite generic: do you have different link/submit buttons that for sending the form and asking for a tip to set a session variable if one of them is clicked or you have just a link to submit the form?

Comment: yes I have 2 different link/submit buttons, I have done now without sessions, "Radu" solution was the best in my case ;) 
Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a hidden input inside the form

```
<input type="hidden" id="link_is_clicked" name="link_is_clicked" value="0"/>
```

then when clicking the link, change the value of that input

```
<a href="..." onclick="document.getElementById('link_is_clicked').value = 1" ...
```

then check for the value of the element on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using someting like this in your HTML to submit your form

```
<input type="submit" name="sender" value="Send" />
```

you can check the `$_POST['sender']` Variable. It will output ether `Send` (clicked on button) or nothing (clicked on link).

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether your form is submitted or not, if so set the session variable.

For example:

```
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0)) //Assuming your form's action is post, use GET otherwise
{
  $_SESSION['somevar'] = 'somevalue';
}
```

Comment: My form can be submitted with another button, I have to test if the user has submitted the form with the button or the link, if with link, I have to put a variable in session.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using JavaScript to make the link submit the form? You can add a hidden input that has value `0`. When the user clicks on the link, change the value of the input to `1` before submitting.